# Laravel validate decimal 0-99.99

Tags: regex, validation, laravel-5, decimalformat

Laravel does not have a validation for `decimal`, so I need a `regex` or other validation method to validate a numeric value of `0 - 99.99`

I have tried

```
required|regex:^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
required|regex:[1-9]\d?(\.\d\d?)?|0\.[1-9]\d?||0\.0[1-9]
required|regex:/[1-9]\d?(\.\d\d?)?|0\.[1-9]\d?||0\.0[1-9]/
required|regex:/[\d]{2}.[\d]{2}/
required|regex:/[\d]{0-2}.[\d]{0,2}/
```

I am either getting "invalid format" when trying to enter `0.05` or unknown modifiers for `preg_match`

any help with the `regex` needed to validate a decimal in `laravel` is appreciated (with optional values before or after decimal

Comment: Are you sure `between:0,99.99` doesn't work?

Comment: it does, I guess I was over thinking it... the demo values on the site never used a decimal, so I never thought to check

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The Laravel `between` validation rule is actually pretty powerful and can handle decimal values as well. So there's no need to use regex just do this:

```
'required|between:0,99.99'
```

Comment: not working   in that case  ['nullable', 'between:1,99999999.99', 'regex:/^(?=.+)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$/']

Comment: Better we use 'gte' and 'lte' they will accept decimal values also

Answer (score 131):

The laravel(5?) between rule does always get it has to parse a decimal, you have to add numeric to it to validate correctly

```
'required|numeric|between:0,99.99',
```

Comment: This fails on 0.5

Comment: late reply but you can try `'required|numeric|between:0.00,99.99',`

Comment: What actually got this working for me was that my AJAX request was a string & in order to validate properly as numeric, I had to cast it as a float prior validation:  

`$request->merge(['inputName' => (float) $request->input('inputName')];`

`required|numeric|0.01,9999.99`

Comment: Beware: Based on the code of 'between': github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Validat‌​ion/… You aren't validating actual number of decimal positions, only that the number is between two real values: The 0 and the 9999.9900000... If you try to validate 9999.981 it will be accepted (and probably rounded to 9999.98 after), but if you try with 9999.991 it will fail.

Answer (score 17):

This works for me:

```
 function rules(){'field' => ['required','numeric', 'min:1','max:99.99', 'regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/']}
```

And if you want to custom the message, then:

```
public function messages()
   {
       return [
        'field.regex' => 'custom your message'
      ];
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

this will work for number allowing two decimal precision:

```
function rules(){

   return [
   'field_name'=> array('regex:/^(?:d*.d{1,2}|d+)$/','min:1','max:10')
        ]; 
}
```

Comment: Why "d" and not "\d" ?    Should it not be        'regex:/^(?:\d*.\d{1,2}|\d+)$/'

Answer (score 2):

From laravel 10 you can validate by the following way:

```
// Must have exactly two decimal places (9.99)...
'price' => 'decimal:2'
 
// Must have between 2 and 4 decimal places...
'price' => 'decimal:2,4'
```

The doc is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-decimal).

Answer (score 1):

this will work for numbers with decimal and without decimals:

> required|gte:0|lte:99

Answer (score -5):

```
 validate()->make([
            'min_commission' => 'required_with:end_page|numeric|min:0|max:0',
            'max_commission' => 'required_with:end_page|numeric|min:0|max:99',

        ]);
```

Comment: There are five existing answers to this question, including a top-rated answer with **98 upvotes**. Are you sure your answer hasn't already been provided? If not, why might someone prefer your approach over the existing approaches proposed? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities? Are there scenarios where your approach is better suited? Explanations are _always_ useful, but are _especially_ important here.