# Float numbers in laravel form

Tags: forms, laravel-5

How I limit the quantity of decimals in a input number of laravelCollective?

Comment: Could you expend on what you would like to do exactly? Maybe with an exemple.

Answer (score 13):

In the Laravel using the FORM, you need change the parameter 'step'.

```
{!! Form::number('preco', null, ['class' => 'form-control','step' => '0.1']) !!}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Laravel between validation rule is actually pretty powerful and can handle decimal values as well. So there's no need to use regex just do this:

```
'required|between:0,99.99'
```

Answer taken from here: [Laravel validate decimal 0-99.99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734046/laravel-validate-decimal-0-99-99)