# Laravel input number allow double values

Tags: php, laravel

I need allow double values. How I can do it? I need allow, doubles like this:

```
- 1,22
- 0,01
- 2,33
```

I can validate with `numeric`:

```
$request->validate(['from' => 'required|numeric']);
```

But then I can write `1,32223`, `22,3322` and others. I need allow only 2 number after comma.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734046/laravel-validate-decimal-0-99-99). Seems like you can use the `between` validation rule as follows

```
numeric|between:0,99.99
```