# How to validate decimal column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column month_1 in table who have `type` is `decimal(12,2)`

how can i validate it in my Request class?

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'month_1' =>'required',
         ];
    }
```

do i have to write `between:0,99.99` ?
will it be applicable to my case also?

Comment: **12.2** or **12,2**?  _12,2_ is not a decimal value

Comment: @sta in migration " $table->decimal('month_1',12,2)->nullable();"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel validate decimal 0-99.99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734046/laravel-validate-decimal-0-99-99)

Comment: @JigneshJoisar please check updated question

Comment: `'month_1' =>'required|between:12,12.30',`

Comment: @sta if its correct then please post it in answer

Comment: Let me explain, **12,2** means : **decimal(p,s)/decimal(12,2)** is a number that has **10/(p-s)** digits before the decimal and **2/s** digit after the decimal. Example : _1111111111.11_

Comment: I think you want to store **month number,date**?  Then it will be **4.2** example : 12.30 or 1.01

Comment: Do you want to validate that any decimal number passed is at most two decimal digits or just that it fits in your database column since the digits after the first two would probably just be ignored

Answer (score 2):

`decimal('month_1', 12, 2)` means total of 12 digits including 2 decimal digits.

So it should be something like:

```
'required|numeric|between:0,9999999999.99'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to store **month number,date**? Then it will be **4.2**

That mean that the database type is `decimal(4, 2)`, then this means that your column is set up to store 4 places (**scale**), with 2 to the right of the decimal (**precision**). You should treat this as a **decimal** CLR type. Example : 12.31,
12.01, 123.4 but not 1234.567 or 12345.67.

You can validate like this :

```
'month_1' =>'required|between:12.01,12.31',
```

This will validate number only, between 12.01 to 12.31